# what are the requirements for spring insight to work on cloudfoundry with a spring app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-roo, cloud-foundry, spring-insight

I have a spring mvc generated app (through ROO) running in cloudfoundry. I could also deploy spring insight into it. but my app shows up with "Insight: not supported on this stack".

Shouldn't it work on the spring stack as well?
what is needed to get it working?

Comment: Would be better if you could list the version numbers of the stacks you are using.

Answer (score 4):

Go to http://insight.cloudfoundry.com/ and log in with your cloudfoundry credentials. After that you will have an extra app deployed http://insight-xxxx.cloudfoundry.com/ where you have a spring insight dashboard containing all your apps.